# react-native-community@datetimepicker build fail on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, datetimepicker

I following the guide for manual installation
https://github.com/react-native-community/datetimepicker#ios

My Pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'evnnpc' do
  use_frameworks!

  platform :ios, '9.0'

  pod 'RNDateTimePicker', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/RNDateTimePicker.podspec'

  # React Native and its dependencies
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  # Other native modules
  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/RNGestureHandler.podspec'
  pod 'RNReanimated', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated/RNReanimated.podspec'
  pod 'RNScreens', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-screens'

  pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios'
  # Required by RNFirebase
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.13.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 6.13.0'

  pod 'react-native-netinfo', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo'
  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'
  pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'
  pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'


  use_native_modules!
end
```

I already run `pod install` after the pod file was updated.
But when run project in XCode 11.3.1, I receive some errors [image: IOS errors]

I don't known why it not success build.
Please help me! Thanks

Comment: Xcode version??

Comment: I built project on Mac Mojave (10.14.4) and XCode 11.3.1

Comment: Ops, I didn't see Requirements (Xcode >= 11.6)

Comment: It works :) thank you so much for suggesting me the XCode version

Comment: Let post this as an answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Xcode version to latest, dependencies were added on 11.6...

Answer (score 0):

Down-grade the version of version datepicker resolved my issue

yarn add @react-native-community/datetimepicker@3.5.2

or

npm add @react-native-community/datetimepicker@3.5.2